# Is it possible to dual OS with some kind of software?

Tags: windows, virtualization

I am using Windows and Ubuntu dualbooted right now, but I have to switch between them a lot. and in rapid succession sometime. Booting Windows *in* linux using VirualBox is ofcourse an option - but I'm wondering if there is some kind of OS which I can boot, which is specifically made to virtualize other OSses, which then can boot windows and Ubuntu at the same time (virtually).

This so that I can suspend Linux, then unsuspend a windows machine for faster continuation of work, or even have them both loaded up at the same time.

And, if there is, would I be able to still play games on the Windows machine? Or would the virtualization completely cut out the native experience.

I tried googling but haven't found a solution that does this.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for something like Vmware [ESXi](https://www.vmware.com/products/esxi-and-esx.html) or [Xen](https://xenproject.org/).

Comment: Or perhaps Proxmox.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu on a secondary drive concurrant with Windows 7](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150394/ubuntu-on-a-secondary-drive-concurrant-with-windows-7)

Comment: I'm going to try out if Xen is what I am trying to do.